# Como especificar o número de caracteres por linha no R ao criar um arquivo txt?

Tags: r

Estou tentando criar um arquivo `.txt` ou `.fasta` em R utilizando a função `cat`, porém preciso limitar as linhas a 60 caracteres apenas e a função `fill` não está funcionando no caso. Segue o código.

```
generateNucSeq<- function(n){
  v = c(sample(nuc, n, replace = TRUE))
  return(paste(v,collapse = ""))
}
```

```
sequence1 <- generateNucSeq(350)
sequence2 <- generateNucSeq(270)
```

```
multiFASTA <- file("multiFASTA.fasta")
cat(">sequence1",sequence1, ">sequence2",sequence2, fill = 60, file = multiFASTA)
close(multiFASTA)
```

Comment: Talvez `help('strwrap')`.

Comment: `strwrap` divide palavras; não sei se há alguma maneira de indicar número fixo de caracteres para quebrar uma string sem espaços brancos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema pode ser resolvido com a ajuda da função `breaklines` mas acho muito complicado. Talvez haja uma maneira mais simples.

```
breaklines <- function(x, width, collapse = " "){
  if(length(x) > 1L){
    warn <- "'x' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"
    warning(warn)
    x <- x[[1]]
  }
  if(width < 2L){
    err <- "minimum 'width' is 2, must account for the separator"
    stop(err)
  } else width <- width - 1L
  n <- nchar(x)
  linhas <- n %/% width
  resto <- n %% width
  y <- character(linhas + (resto > 0L))
  for(i in seq.int(linhas)){
    y[i] <- substr(x, 1, width)
    x <- substring(x, width + 1L)
  }
  if(resto > 0L){
    y[i + 1L] <- x
  }
  paste(y, collapse = collapse)
}

generateNucSeq <- function(n){
  v <- c(sample(nuc, n, replace = TRUE))
  paste(v, collapse = "")
}

set.seed(2021)
nuc <- c("G", "A", "C", "T")
sequence1 <- generateNucSeq(350)
sequence2 <- generateNucSeq(270)

multiFASTA <- file("multiFASTA.fasta")
txt <- paste(">sequence1", sequence1, ">sequence2", sequence2, "\n")
txt <- breaklines(txt, 61)
cat(strwrap(txt, width = 61), file = multiFASTA, sep = "\n")
close(multiFASTA)
```

Comment: Sim, um pouco complicado mas funciona. Valeu

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar `gsub` e uma expressão regular que insira o marcador de quebra de linha (`\n`) a cada n caracteres. Por exemplo:

```
gsub("(.{1,4})", "\\1\n", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN")
#> [1] "ABCD\nEFGH\nIJKL\nMN\n"
```

Pode escrever como uma função, aproveitando para incluir nela a criação da linha com o nome:

```
generateNucSeq <- function(n) {
  v = sample(c("A", "C", "G", "T"), n, replace = TRUE)
  paste(v, collapse = "")
}

makeFastaLine <- function(sequence, n = 60) {
  seqName <- deparse(substitute(sequence))
  seqWrpd <- gsub(paste0("(.{1,", n, "})"), "\\1\n", sequence)
  paste0(">", seqName, "\n", seqWrpd)
}

sequence1 <- generateNucSeq(350)
sequence2 <- generateNucSeq(270)

multiFASTA <- file("multiFASTA.fasta")
  writeLines(makeFastaLine(sequence1), makeFastaLine(sequence2), con = multiFASTA)
close(multiFASTA)

readLines("multiFASTA.fasta")
#>  [1] ">sequence1"
#>  [2] "GTTTCGGCTCGTGCGGGTGTGCAGTCCATCGTCTCAGTCCAAGTGGTATTCAACCTTGGT"
#>  [3] "AACAGGAGGATCTCCGCCGTTATCTTCCACACTCATATGCATATGACATCGGACAAGGGG"
#>  [4] "AATCTGTCATGGCTGCCTAGTAGGTCGCTATAAACCAGGCTGCTCTCCGGCAGACAGCAT"
#>  [5] "TCCGCATCATCCGTCGTTGGGTTCCATTCGTCGCTCTATCATAATAGTTAATCAGGCAAC"
#>  [6] "CCGGTGGTAGTCCCATCACGGACTTAGATGAGAACCTACGATACTGCCGTAACAGCGCGC"
#>  [7] "GACTTACCACATCGTCGAGTTGGACGGGTCACGCTGCTAGGTCATTACGT"
#>  [8] ">sequence2"
#>  [9] "CCCGCTCAGTTAATCTTGATCACTGAAAGCCTATCCAGCTGCACACAGACGAACTGTGTA"
#> [10] "GTTATTATCTTTAATCGTAACCGTTACAGCGTTCCACCAAACTTTATCAATATTGGGAAG"
#> [11] "GAGTGATATACATAAAGCTTTTCCGGACCGGGGTTTGCATTGGGAACAGGAGCCTTTTAG"
#> [12] "TATCCAAAGATACGAGGTTAGCGCCGCCGTATCCAAGATCTATCTGCGTCGGTAACTTGA"
#> [13] "GTTGGAATGCGAGCACGAGTGTTAGCTCCG"
```